# Get values from NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` that has three columns with multiple lines with float values, like this:

```
-0.06,  -0.49,  -0.76;
-1.05,  -0.63,  -0.77;
0.73,  -0.32,  -0.62;
-0.08,  -0.61,  -1.00;
0.15,  -0.42,  -0.91;
```

I used this lines to define the `NSMutableArray` (anArrayAcel):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@",self.accX.text,self.accY.text, self.accZ.text];
[anArrayAcel addObject:str];
```

I need access this data to be used in other function. How can I access the values through  specific indexes?

Comment: Why are your values added as a string of three values? Why not have an array of arrays of numbers?

Comment: Maybe add a NSMutableArray obj to the NSMutableArray instead? That way you can access it like so: Example to get the first column's and first row's value: `[[anArrayAcel objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: You are asking how to use `anAreayAcel` in a different method, orfunction, or how to extract the data from `anArrayAcel` to use in a different function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can design a class named Acel as below:

```
// Acel.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Acel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat accX;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat accY;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat accZ;

- (instancetype)initWithAccX:(CGFloat)accX accY:(CGFloat)accY accZ:(CGFloat)accZ;

@end
```

and .m is as below:

```
// Acel.m  
#import "Acel.h"
@implementation Acel
- (instancetype)initWithAccX:(CGFloat)accX accY:(CGFloat)accY accZ:(CGFloat)accZ{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.accX = accX;
        self.accY = accY;
        self.accZ = accZ;
    }
    return self;

}
@end
```

ViewController as below:

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *acels;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.acels = [@[] mutableCopy];
    Acel *acel0 = [[Acel alloc] initWithAccX:-1.1f accY:0.2f accZ:0.3f];
    Acel *acel1 = [[Acel alloc] initWithAccX:-1.1444f accY:0.22f accZ:0.33f];
    Acel *acel2 = [[Acel alloc] initWithAccX:-1.1411f accY:0.255f accZ:0.333f];
    [_acels addObject:acel0];
    [_acels addObject:acel1];
    [_acels  addObject:acel2];

    [self accessAccel1X];
}

- (void)accessAccel1X{
    Acel * acel1 = self.acels[1];
    NSLog(@"%f", acel1.accX);

}
```

In my opinion,it is more elegant compared with two-dimensional array.
Because we don't need do like [0][1] and we avoid double circulation if you want to  iterate through arrays,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need an array of arrays. You made an array of `NSString`s instead.

Here is one way to do it:

```
NSMutableArray *row = [
    @[
        [self.accX.text floatValue]
    ,   [self.accY.text floatValue]
    ,   [self.accZ.text floatValue]
    ]
    mutableCopy
];
[anArrayAcel addObject:row];
```

The idea is to create an array of `NSMutableArray`s, presumably in an event handler inside which you add rows to your array. If you do not need the nested arrays to be mutable, skip the `mutableCopy` part.

Now you can access your data as follows:

```
float x = anArrayAcel[row][0];
float y = anArrayAcel[row][1];
float z = anArrayAcel[row][2];
```

Note: if all rows are going to have exactly three values, `x`, `y`, and `z`, you may be better off creating a class to represent three `float`s instead of using a nested array.

Comment: Good call on creating a class with properties :)